microfactory_Linux: cannot execute binary file: exe Format not valid
I'm trying to boot up Android cuttlefish on the Raspi OS,based on Debian Bookworm emulated with qemu-system-aarch64 on top of Ubuntu 24.04 X64 bit. The qemu parameters that I've used are the following :
qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt-9.0,virtualization=on,gic_version=3 -cpu max \

-smp 8 -m 8G -kernel /mnt/zroot-133/zroot-133/A_FILES/OS/Linux/RaspiOS/Image \

-append "root=/dev/vda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw panic=0 console=ttyAMA0 kvm-arm.mode=nested" \

-drive format=raw,file=/mnt/zroot-133/zroot-133/A_FILES/OS/Linux/RaspiOS/2024-07-04-raspios-bookworm-arm64-big.img,if=none,id=hd0 \

-device virtio-blk,drive=hd0,bootindex=0 \

-netdev tap,id=mynet0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no \

-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01 -device usb-ehci \

-device usb-kbd -device virtio-tablet-pci -usb -device virtio-serial-pci \

-spice port=5930,disable-ticketing=on \

-device virtserialport,chardev=spicechannel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \

-chardev spicevmc,id=spicechannel0,name=vdagent -display spice-app &`

I've found this nice tutorial and I'm trying to follow it :
https://2net.co.uk/blog/cuttlefish-android12.html
with some differences. Since I'm using Raspi OS / Debian Bookworm emulated with qemu-system-aarch64 and Android 13,I've used these commands :
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-13.0.0_r6

$ repo sync -c

$ source build/envsetup.sh

$ lunch aosp_cf_arm64_phone-userdebug

$ m

and inside the vm I did :
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/droplet/mnt/zroot-133/zroot-133/A_FILES/OS/Android/2net-co-uk/aosp_cf_arm64_phone-userdebug $ source build/envsetup

pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/droplet/mnt/zroot-133/zroot-133/A_FILES/OS/Android/2net-co-uk/aosp_cf_arm64_phone-userdebug $ lunch aosp_cf_arm64_phone-userdebug

but I've got this error :
/mnt/droplet/mnt/zroot-133/zroot-133/A_FILES/OS/Android/2net-co-uk/aosp_cf_arm64_phone-userdebug/build/blueprint/microfactory/microfactory.bash: riga 62:

/mnt/droplet/mnt/zroot-133/zroot-133/A_FILES/OS/Android/2net-co-uk/aosp_cf_arm64_phone-userdebug/out/microfactory_Linux: cannot execute binary file: exe Format not valid

I don't understand why,since as u can see below,I'm sure that I'm using the right architecture :
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/droplet/mnt/zroot-133/zroot-133/A_FILES/OS/Android/2net-co-uk/aosp_cf_arm64_phone-userdebug/out/target/product $ ls

vsoc_arm64

I expect to be able to boot up Android Cuttlefish for arm64.

Emulating a different CPU architecture always requires more CPU and CPU is very limited in a Raspberry. Why do you emulate an x64 Linux on a Raspberry?

Hello. I'm not using -machine raspi4b,but -machine virt-9.0,so I don't have the raspberry 4 limitations. Infact I've used -smp 8 and -m 8G. I'm not emulating x64 Linux on a Raspberry. I want to boot Android Cuttlefish arm64 on the Raspi OS based on Debian Bookworm for arm64. Since the architectures are the same,it should work. Or not ? Ubuntu 24.04 is the OS where I run qemu that emulates RaspiOS. I've created this vm because when I tried to do the same on my Jetson Nano it failed. So,I changed OS to change kernel version,thinking that the kernel used by the Jetson nano (4.9) was too old.

Running an emulator (Android) within an emulator (Raspi) is never a good idea. On a regular Ubuntu 24.04 I would simply use the Android emulator from Android Studio.

I've already did that and it worked. Now It's the turn to make work Android Cuttlefish.
